# In Swift how to obtain the "invisible" escape characters in a string variable into another variable

Tags: string, swift, escaping

In Swift I can create a String variable such as this:

```
let s = "Hello\nMy name is Jack!"
```

And if I use s, the output will be:

```
Hello
My name is Jack!
```

(because the \n is a linefeed)

But what if I want to programmatically obtain the raw characters in the s variable?  As in if I want to actually do something like:

```
let sRaw = s.raw
```

I made the .raw up, but something like this. So that the literal value of sRaw would be:

```
Hello\nMy name is Jack!
```

and it would literally print the string, complete with literal "\n"

Thank you!

Comment: I think you will have to add some "" around the \n because it a newline so to print it out you may have to change it into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newline is the "raw character" contained in the string.

How exactly you formed the string (in this case from a string literal with an escape sequence in source code) is not retained (it is only available in the source code, but not preserved in the resulting program). It would look exactly the same if you read it from a file, a database, the concatenation of multiple literals, a multi-line literal, a numeric escape sequence, etc.

If you want to print newline as `\n` you have to convert it back (by doing text replacement) -- but again, you don't know if the string was really created from such a literal.

Comment: Yes, it does seem that ultimately I need to be doing text replacement. There is one item I am really trying to accomplish which is to replace single backslashes with two backslashes.  But if I think about it, the only instances of single backslashes are those associated with a very small subset of other characters such as double quotes. So ultimately I can handle those by string replacement as you have indicated. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with escaped characters such as `\n`:

```
let secondaryString = "really"
let s = "Hello\nMy name is \(secondaryString) Jack!"
let find = Character("\n")
let r = String(s.characters.split(find).joinWithSeparator(["\\","n"]))
print(r) // -> "Hello\nMy name is really Jack!"
```

However, once the string `s` is generated the `\(secondaryString)` has already been interpolated to "really" and there is no trace of it other than the replaced word. I suppose if you already know the interpolated string you could search for it and replace it with "\\(secondaryString)" to get the result you want. Otherwise it's gone.

Comment: You are right. I upvoted your answer because it provides additional detail. Are you aware of string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString ? It is another way to replace text I have found. Thank you very much.

Comment: `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` is from the Foundation bridge to `NSString`. I prefer to not use Cocoa classes if there is a Swift equivalent. For a single `Character` like `\n` my code works just as well.